# How do i write this in php 5.6?

Tags: php

I am having problems fulfilling a client requirement to convert this code to PHP 5.6. It is currently in php 7, but i want it to be in php 5.6.

```
if ((float)$stack->top() < 20 && (float)$part < 20 ?? (float)$part < $stack->top() )
{ 
    return $stack->top().(isset($parts[$idx - $stack->count()]['suffix']) ? $parts[$idx - $stack->count()]['suffix'] : '')." ".$mutate(array_slice($parts, $idx));

}
```

This is what i am trying.

```
if ((float)$stack->top() < 20 && (float)$part < 20 )
{ 

   return $stack->top().(isset($parts[$idx - $stack->count()]['suffix']) ? $parts[$idx - $stack->count()]['suffix'] : '')." ".$mutate(array_slice($parts, $idx));

}
else if( (float)$part < $stack->top())
{
   return $stack->top().(isset($parts[$idx - $stack->count()]['suffix']) ? $parts[$idx - $stack->count()]['suffix'] : '')." ".$mutate(array_slice($parts, $idx));

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to downgrade from a supported version of PHP to an EOL version?

Comment: client requirement actually